# Trying to echo text from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jtextarea, keylistener

I can't really see where the mistakes are with this.

I've set up a KeyListener for the textAreaTop component, so every time a key is pressed, a string is sent to the server, which echoes it back to the teaxtAreaBottom component. I'm aware stdIn is not being used yet.

When the first key is pressed, a connection is made, but when the second key is pressed I get the following error: Couldn't get I/O for the connection to localhost. Also, nothing is appended to the textAreaBottom component.

//Client

```
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    String hostName = "localhost";
     int portNumber = 4000;

    try (Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(),
                    true);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
         BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

        String userInput = textAreaTop.getText();
        out.println(userInput);
        textAreaBottom.setText(null);
        textAreaBottom.setText(in.readLine());

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
         System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to "
                + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    }
```

// Server

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int portNumber = 4000;

    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("connection accepted");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
                true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(inputLine);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out
                .println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                        + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you closing the connection at the end of each keyPressed event?

Since you are opening a new connection each time with a Socket over the same hostName and portNumber, you should make sure to close the connection.

Comment: Hi Marcin. I guess I'm not... everything to do with the sockets/network connection is in the code blocks above. I have it working now though.

The way i've set up the program, it connects each time a key is pressed (I think), so should I close the I/O streams and socket after each key is pressed?

I was thinking I could close all three in a "finally" block.

Comment: Try putting `echoSocket.close()` at the end of the try block.

Comment: search here about Java + Socket + EventDispatchThread (e.i. EDT), start with more in Concurency in Swing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of two little flaws:

1. You should implement `keyReleased()` instead of `keyPressed()`, because the text in the `textAreaTop` is being updated after `keyPressed()` being called. So when the `keyReleased()` method is being called your `textAreaTop` has the latest text you have input.
2. You shouldn't create that `Socket` object everytime you press a key. You should define that `Socket` and the references to the input/output `Streams` **outside** of the `keyReleased`(former keyPressed) anonymous class and method. So every time you press a key the only job to do is to get the text from `textAreaTop` and `out.println(text)` to the server. In this case I have tested the code and it's working properly.

Good Luck.